# How do you integrate drools-workbench with drools project?

Tags: drools

How do you integrate drools-workbench with drools project?

Answer (score 2):

**Short answer:** Drools Consultant.

**Medium answer:** The Workbench uses a git repository to store the projects. When these projects are built, the result is a maven artifact. You can either integrate at the source-level (read rules from the git repo) or at the binary-level (create KieContainers from maven artifacts).

**Long answer:** Read the Manual ([KIE Concepts](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.0.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_kiechapter), [Build & Deploy](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.0.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_wb.quickstartbuildanddeloy), [Workbench Repository](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/7.0.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#_wb.vfsrepository))

Hope it helps,